# Var dynamic in xslt/xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, dynamic, var

I need to create a dynamic var in my code.

```
<repeat ...>
.
.
.
    <div id="prixsejour"> <output ref="cart/priceTaxeSejourTotal-"/> </div>
</repeat>
```

When i'm in my loop, I need to do a output which "up" in every round. Like this :

```
<output ref="cart/priceTaxeSejourTotal-1"/>
<output ref="cart/priceTaxeSejourTotal-2"/>
<output ref="cart/priceTaxeSejourTotal-3"/>
.
.
.
```

Have you got an idea ? 
Thanks

Comment: You mention XSLT in the title, but I don't see any XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

It is done ! I don't knew it, we can add an index on the loop. This is my solution :

```
<repeat ...  index="cpt">
.
.
.
    <div id="prixsejour"> <output ref="cart/priceTaxeSejourTotal-${$cpt}"/> </div>
</repeat>
```

Comment: What language is this?